# How to add Test name and module to Test docstring in result?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, nose

I am using `django_nose`'s `NoseTestSuiteRunner` to run tests. Currently if the test has docstring it will be printed on console for the test (`TestCase.ShortDescrption()`) and if it's `None` name of the test (`TestCase.id()`) is printed, I want to add `TestCase.id()` to `TestCase.ShortDescription()` so that TestCase.id() is printed regardless of docstring's presence.

sample test:

```python
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_bar_1(self):
          """ this is docstring 1"""
          pass

      def test_bar_2(self):
          """ this is docstring 2"""
          self.fail()
```

so for the result instead of

```
this is a docstring 1 ... ok
this is a docstring 2 ... Fail
```

I want

```
test_bar_1(path.to.test.Foo) this is a docstring 1 ... ok
test_bar_2(path.to.test.Foo) this is a docstring 2 ... Fail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the implementation of `TestCase.shortDescription()` to return both `TestCase.__str__` and `TestCase._testMethodDoc` as following:

```
class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

      def shortDescription(self):
          doc = self.__str__() +": "+self._testMethodDoc
          return doc or None 

      def test_bar_1(self):
          """ this is docstring 1"""
          pass

      def test_bar_2(self):
          """ this is docstring 2"""
          self.fail()
```

so the result of `nosetests -v <module-name>.py` is:

```
test_bar_1(path.to.test.Foo): this is a docstring 1 ... ok
test_bar_2(path.to.test.Foo): this is a docstring 2 ... Fail
```

Note: I will add a nose plugin for it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you supply the `--with-id` option to your nosetests command you can achieve what you are looking for.

http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/testid.html

Comment: This will add an id, by id I meant unittest.TestCase.id() which returns the whole test name and path. https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.id